# Can VS2010 generate NunitTest cases?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nunit-2.5.9

There is option of Create Unit Tests in VS2010. 
It creates a separate test project and uses MS test frame work. Is it possible for configure VS to use Nunit framework to create unit test cases?

Answer (score 0):

From what i know Visual Studio generates only MSTests. But there are many commercial tools (You can always evaluate :)) which are quite helpful.
For example:

- [Other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357059/unit-test-case-generator)
- [Parasoft dotTEST](http://www.parasoft.com/jsp/products/dottest.jsp)

Probably by your own You will find few more.